# How to Continue an .htaccess Rule

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

looking for a little assistance with htaccess rewrite rules:

Original URL
- https://www.example.com/resources-categories/**fallbeispiele**?**lang=de**

Desired result:
- https://www.example.com/**de**/resources-categories/**white-papers**

Moving around the following htaccess code will process only one rule, I'm researching and finding that [C] will continue, but that's not working.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^[^&](?:\w+)=(\w+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)fallbeispiele(.*)$ $1white-papers$2 [R=301,C] 
RewriteRule ^ %1%{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]
```

Is there an order (in terms of RewriteCond) that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(?:\w+)=(\w+)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)fallbeispiele(?:.*)$ %1/$1white-papers? [L,R=301,QSD]
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is looking for a similar solution:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(?:\w+)=(\w+)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) %1%{REQUEST_URI}? [L,R=301]
```

I couldn't use QSD because the Apache version was 2.2

Also, if you're testing with https://htaccess.madewithlove.be - it's not working correctly so don't put all your eggs in one basket, try it out on your own server/staging before disregarding